Conditional formatting a cell based on if a cell in a range is 0
I'm trying to make the below cells (E5 or E7) highlight red if any of the cells in another column are 0. I only want E5 (or E7) to be highlighted, not the cell in the corresponding row if the cell in column Y is blank

For the formula below I put a 0 in cell H5 as a reference.
I tried doing =isnumber(Match(H5,Y3:Y50,0)) but it would always highlight the cells in the above picture, as  there were blanks in the column.
There is probably a very simple solution, but i've been struggling to find a similar enough question in online forums that will work for this.
Thanks in advance

what about checking the length? ie len() greater than 0 ?

are you able to use len on a range of cells? I'm only looking at formatting one cell (E5) to red if there is a cell in the range Y3:Y50 that is 0, but also not blank. i've already got the cells in column Y to highlight if it is 0, but the person using the spreadsheet tends not to check thoroughly, so i'm trying to make it clear when there is an error so they check the file properly.

So, two methods using conditional formatting:
one based on the cell value less tahn 1 and the other using len(), note how the len() is using a relative reference in the CF rule.

Then adding 7 in cell D5 gives the results:


The way that i'm looking for it to to work is for it to check if any cells in a range are 0, the problem i have with using less than 1 is that the column is percentages, so all of them are less than one.

I think I might have found a workaround/solution. If I use =product(Y3:Y50)=0 in CF then its highlighting. This looks to work, as if there's a proper 0 in the range then the product should always amount to 0.

@Midge431 so you have not clearly looked at method 2 as it checks a different range to where the conditional formatting is applied AND the range that it checks is not a percentage but just a number.

this looks like it will only format the cell in that column, rather than having it as a static cell and looking at the whole range of cells. I'm not looking to have E19 highlight red if Y19 is blank, i need E5 to be highlighting red if any of the cells in Y3:Y50 is a set value of 0 (as it only shows a flat zero if there is an error).

@Midge431 you should then provide a clear and accurate question as I have put together an answer based on what you provided which I added data to to show two possible methods.

It has been amended, but I'm currently waiting for the colleague to run through the process to check if my product solution works as intended.
